# Unbiase coin toss using the C++11 random library

Tags: c++11, random, coin-flipping

I have a program that needs to generate very many 0/1 random values. Because this is needed many times and in different part of the code, I wish to have a time efficient and easy to use random generator to perform this task.

I started using the standard library `<random>` from C++11 to do so but the documentation is quite sparse and sometimes even contradictory.

My questions were the following:

- Should I extract bits myself (using masking on unsigned long long) or can the library do it on its own?

  Indeed, I found a [document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3551.pdf) that says:

> Better still, standard-conforming distributions cope with all engine
>   corner cases, even unlikely ones. For example, if an engine delivers
>   fewer bits per call than needed, the distribution will make multiple
>   calls until it has enough bits to let it satisfy the entire desired
>   range of variates. On the other hand, if an engine produces more bits
>   than needed, a distribution is free to cache the excess for use the
>   next time it is called.

- Does this mean that it will automatically use only one bit to
  generate 0 and 1?

  - If yes, should I use the `uniform_int_distribution` or the `bernoulli_distributio` (bool) distribution with probability 0.5? (What would be most time efficient?)
  - If no, what is the most time efficient way to generate a lot of good quality random bits with the random library? Which distribution with which parameters? Are all the bits really random or is there some bit bias?

Comment: Whenever you have a question about "efficiency" you need to specify what kind of efficiency you're after. Memory consumption? CPU load? Speed? Something else? And then you should implement each version you are thinking about and *measure*. And not just once or twice, do it in a loop a million times or so, to get a nice average, and if possible do it under different loads and different environments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry. I meant speed. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If I just implement and test the speed it will still not answer the main question: How many random bits is the random generator generating in a coin-toss experiment: 2, 32, random distribution dependent, platform dependent... ?

Comment: Additionally, for my last question, if I take the fastest way I can end up with some very nasty bit biases and this can be very tricky to detect.

Comment: I suspect plain `uniform_int_distribution` with `mersenne_twister_engine` would be "good enough". Mersenne Twister has the "best" randomness, and `uniform_int_distribution` shouldn't consume excessive random input when the range is a power of 2 (it would take a really poor implementation to consume more than a word of randomness to produce output). Optimizing beyond that should wait until you actually profile and show you have a bottleneck.

Comment: As the caching note indicates, it might only consume a single bit to generate a distribution between 0 and 1. Aside from that, you'd want to look at the engines more than the distributions: The standards are there to avoid bad distributions (e.g. implementing `uniform_int_distribution` in terms of strict remainder and addition with non-power of 2 ranges); they rely on the engine's randomness guarantees to produce "good" output. If they misbehave, that's an implementation quirk; the standard is fairly explicit about not introducing bias. Regardless, coin tosses should not have bias issues.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the answer. The document cited in the question states that unused the distribution "is free" to used them later on. Does it mean it always catches the excess if needed or does it depend on how the call to the distribution is made?

Comment: @Prolix: I think that means it's up to the implementation. Some may throw away the bits, some may cache, etc. So you'll get different behaviors on different compiler/library versions.